# Threaded vial or similar container?

Tags: hardware-identification

I've turned a "magic wand" as a Christmas gift for my niece.  If you're familiar with the Harry Potter stories you probably know that wands usually contain something inside of them (i.e. Unicorn hairs, dragon heartstrings, phoenix feathers.)  Since my niece is a huge animal lover I'm talking with the local zoo about getting something special.  I would like to place these in a small vial that can be screwed into a threaded insert in the bottom of the wand.

I've been looking for something like this all morning but searching online tends to give me large vials, or items related to the medical industry.  Can anyone here point me toward a suitable product, or recommend better search terms that might get me closer to what I actually want?  I'm open to alternative ways of accomplishing this as well if anyone has suggestions.

Comment: I presume you want threaded so that it can be removed from the wand (and opened?), or is it just for ease of installation?

Comment: I thought it would be nice if it could be unscrewed and removed so that the contents of the vial could be seen.  But the vial itself would remain closed.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to seal the vial yourself, so that the cap can remain in the wand and the vial itself can simply be unscrewed from it?

Comment: Possibly. I've been thinking that maybe I'm over complicating it. Maybe all I really need is a decorative threaded cap. The vial can simply be dropped into a hole I drill and then the decorative cap screws in to cover it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to place these in a small vial that can be screwed into a threaded insert in the bottom of the wand.

I think something like a [necklace vial](https://www.etsy.com/listing/232682242/20-pcs-flat-bottom-tube-vials-bottles?ref=market) will work for your purpose:

[image: vial]

If you've ever been to a mall and seen the kiosks where someone will write your name on a grain of rice, these are pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I searched for something like this in the past and came across [DiscountVials](http://www.discountvials.com/vials/) which at the very least will give you ideas of what is available out there.  I ended up not ordering anything, so can't actually make a recommendation.

If you want very tiny, my immediate thought was a perfume sample vial.  You might even be able to grab one of these at the perfume counter of a department store and clean it very well with alcohol.

[image]

For something with threads, I thought of what I can only call a "crack vial" because I've only ever seen them used in TV and movies to hold drugs for some reason...  I believe I have seen vials like this at the Container Store.

[image]